# 2d Kalman filter with acceleration

Tags: python-3.x, kalman-filter

I would like to implement a kalman filter in Python for some tracking software I'm working on. It is a 2D coordinate system using a single vector x for position, velocity and acceleration of x and y coordinates,

[image]

I am using the following update and predict method:

```
# UPDATE
y = Z - (H * x)
S = H * P * H.T + R  # residual convariance
K = P * H.T * S.I    # Kalman gain
x = x + K*y
I = np.matrix(np.eye(F.shape[0])) # identity matrix
P = (I - K*H)*P

# PREDICT x, P based on motion
x = F*x
P = F*P*F.T + Q

return x, P
```

Using other resources I have come up with the following state transition matrix and measurement matrix but am not sure how correct they are:

```
F = np.matrix('''
      1. 0. 1. 0. 0.5 0.;
      0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0.5;
      0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0.;
      0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1.;
      0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0.;
      0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.
      '''),
 H = np.matrix('''
      1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.;
      0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.;
      0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0.;
      0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.'''),
```

Basically it doesn't work and makes my tracked path more jittery and I have no clue where I'm going wrong. Can anyone help?

Comment: F and H look ok to me (the latter if your measurements are position and accelaration). The key to tuning kalman filters is the correct choice of the observation error covariance matrix R and the process noise covariance matrix Q. What are you using?

Comment: Old question... but if you're still working on this I would recommend checking out the `pykalman` library [here](https://pykalman.github.io/). It has lots of useful estimation methods built in to help with estimating covariance matrices etc.